# Matplotlib widget (ipympl) not working in Jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter, ipython, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

Which backend do I use?

```
%matplotlib
Using matplotlib backend: module://ipympl.backend_nbagg
```

It shows the plot correctly and I am able to save it interactively, however, the zoom function and all the other interactive function do not work. I am using Version 0.9.2, jupyterlab Version 3.6.3 on Linux.

Can it be that I am missing some packages? Any ideas?

Comment: Your title and first few lines of your post seem at odds? You aren't detailing what you are actually using to attempt to use `ipympl`. What happens if you follow [the basic example in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#ipympl)? If I go [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dsurface_plot-binder) press `launch k3d examples in JupyterLab` badge (middle badge) to get a session served via MyBinder where `ipympl` is already installed and set up properly in JupyterLab, and then I run the 'Basic Example' code in JupyterLab, it works  as the example shows it should.

Comment: And I know [0.9.2 had a least one issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl/issues/524#issuecomment-1456438678), and so I would suggest updating to 0.9.3 that was released in February.